# After applying the new parameters in PostgreSQL, the pg_dump log is directed to the console

Tags: postgresql, logging

I changes this settings:

```
log_destination: 'syslog'
syslog_facility: 'LOCAL0'
syslog_ident: 'postgres'
syslog_sequence_numbers: on
syslog_split_messages: off
lc_messages: 'en_US.UTF-8'
client_min_messages: log
log_checkpoints: off
log_connections: on
log_disconnections: on
log_duration: off
log_error_verbosity: default
log_hostname: on
log_min_error_statement: info
log_min_messages: info
log_statement: 'all'
logging_collector: off
log_line_prefix: '%n | %a | %u | %d | %r | %i | %e '
```

And after applying this settings, i start to dump db with command:

```
`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -t "_accumrg10889" -Fc database > /db/postgresql/14/backup/test.gz`
```

i see this:
LOG:

```
statement: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
LOG:  statement: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_is_in_recovery()
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET DATESTYLE = ISO
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET INTERVALSTYLE = POSTGRES
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET extra_float_digits TO 3
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET synchronize_seqscans TO off
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET statement_timeout = 0
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET lock_timeout = 0
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET row_security = off
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: BEGIN
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ, READ ONLY
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: RESET search_path
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SELECT c.oid
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
ON n.oid OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) ANY
>     (array['r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p'])
AND c.relname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(_accumrg10889)$' COLLATE pg_catalog.default
AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)

pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
pg_dump: LOG:  statement: SELECT x.tableoid, x.oid, x.extname, n.nspname, x.extrelocatable, x.extversion, x.extconfig, x.extcondition FROM pg_extension x JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = x.extnamespace
```

etc...

probably log_statement: 'all' is guilty.

i think it is usefull, but i don't understand which parameter directs it in console

Comment: It can be turned off by setting `log_statement = 'none'` (default) or keeping `log_statement = 'all'` but setting `client_min_messages = notice` (default)

Answer (score 0):

after several tests i found dependencies - why pg_dump logs directly in console:

client_min_messages: log
&
log_statement: 'all'
Thanks)